# The requested endpoint 'https://<clustername>/v1/rest/mgmt' does not exist

Tags: python, azure, cluster-computing, azure-data-explorer, adx

I created a new cluster in Azure and using python api, I want to create a database and tables inside it. However, it gives me error that my cluster endpoint does not exists.
Error: `The requested endpoint 'https://<clustername>/v1/rest/mgmt' does not exist`

My code:

```
client_id = <client-id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
AAD_TENANT_ID = <AAD_TENANT_ID>


query = .create table Raw_production_replicaatenant_785(TimeStamp:datetime,ID:int,StatusCode:dynamic,R1:real)

def Kusto_Execute(db,query):
    cluster = "https://<cluster-name>/" 
    kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(cluster, client_id, client_secret, AAD_TENANT_ID)
    client = KustoClient(kcsb)

    response = client.execute(db, query)
```

Can anyone identity the issue? For clarity, my api is using active directory authentication method to authenticate with azure cluster and I have have admin rights to this app on my cluster as well.

More information: the same code works for my other azure cluster. The error is occurring on new cluster. Do I need a new aad app registered for it?

Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code, what you have tried to create the database and tables inside data explorer?

Comment: I have edited my question and required code is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same error in my environment:

[image]

> azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoServiceError:The requested endpoint
> 'https://<cluster name.location.kusto.window.net/v1/rest/mgmt' does not exist

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong database name in the code.

After I tried with the correct database with the below code it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table

client_id = "Client_id"
client_secret ="Client_secret"
AAD_TENANT_ID = "Tenant_id"


def Kusto_Execute():
    cluster = "https://<your clustername>.location.kusto.windows.net" 
    query = ".create table Raw_production_replicaatenant_785(TimeStamp:datetime,ID:int,StatusCode:dynamic,R1:real)"
    db="<your database name>"
    kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(cluster, client_id, client_secret, AAD_TENANT_ID)
    client = KustoClient(kcsb)
    response = client.execute(db,query)
    df = dataframe_from_result_table(response.primary_results[0])
    print(df)

Kusto_Execute()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Query data using the Azure Data Explorer Python library | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/python-query-data)